# VS macro for RunToCursor functionality with ignoring breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-macros

I tried to create a simple macro to ignore breakpoints when doing RunToCursor.

But for some reason the RunToCursor call doesn't work at all ("Operation not supported") and breakpoint states aren't properly reset either. Some are reactivated but not all. Any ideas?

```
Sub RunToLineAndIgnoreBreakpoints()
    Dim bptStates(DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Count - 1) As Boolean


    Dim i = 0
    For Each bpt As Breakpoint In DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints
        bptStates(i) = bpt.Enabled
        i += 1
        bpt.Enabled = False
    Next

    Try
        DTE.Debugger.RunToCursor(True)
        '       Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        i = 0
        For Each bpt As Breakpoint In DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints
            bpt.Enabled = bptStates(i)
            i += 1
        Next
    End Try
End Sub
```